# mock function from js file in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a js file loaded in my html:

```
<script src="https://domain.code.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And to use it in a service i declare it:

```
declare function someFunction(value: string): string;
```

Now, when testing this service, I want to call a stubbed version in my jasmine test. Can anyone tell me how to do so?

Comment: Did you try with `someFunction = jasmine.createSpy()` ?

Comment: It will be very difficult if you do not share what have you tried in your test so far.